# Inconsistent number parsing python2?

Tags: python, numbers, python-2.x, literals

In Python different systems for representing numbers are allowed:

```
>>> 11 # Decimal
11
>>> 011 # Octal
9
>>> 0x11 # Hexadecimal
17
>>> 0b11 # Binary
3
```

After I typed `0175` once in production instead of `0.175` I became wary of the different representations. I wonder why this behavior is not consistent though, consider:

```
>>> 1E017 # expected octal
1e+17
>>> 1E17 # expected decimal
1e+17
```

Comment: literal `011` is octal for `9` in python 2. In python 3 this is not possible anymore. You have to use the `0o` prefix to define octal numbers. So python 3 => problem solved.

Comment: Of course it's consistent. You just need to learn it more! The general rule is: to same symbol is same value. As soon as you change it, they will both change.

Comment: You are using floating point notation. Why would that notation support octal or hexadecimal?

Comment: Note that C [uses the same syntax](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal), and [C floating point literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal) don't support octal exponents *either*. So Python is being very consistent here.

Comment: I find the insight that `1e10` produces a float valuable in itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xEy` where `abs(x) < 10` and `y` is a whole number is called [scientific notation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) and is equal to `x * 10**y`. It always represents a decimal, and both `x` and `y` are decimal as well.